# At the end of the WWII, the Cold War had begun

Tags: simple-past-vs-past-perfect

I've stumpled upon a peculiar usage of the Past Perfect Tense.

***At the end of the WWII, the Cold War had begun.** The world would lay divided between two superpowers.*

This context seems suitable rather for the Past Simple Tense.

I would be thankful for any hints as to why this tense was used.

Have a good day,
Damian

Comment: You need to provide the context and a link if available. Context will tell you if there was a past action  used as a point of reference.

Comment: Hello, Taman. Please link to the source. The suspect use of 'lay' for 'lie' gives one to think the source material (or transmission) is of queryable quality. // Though I'd almost certainly (context often licenses unexpectedly) use 'By' instead of 'At', I'd use past perfect here as in the example. I think the past simple here doesn't immerse one in the situation as well (though your alternative is certainly fine on grammatical grounds).

Comment: The Cold War did not begin until WWII ended. So "At the end of the WWII, the Cold War had begun" cannot be true. Another hint of non-native speaker is using 'the' in "the WWII", whereas it would be more natural in, for example, "the second World War."

Comment: Ah, historical context demanding a better example. // If someone is (probably unhelpfully as 1947 is the date usually accepted) arguing that the Cold War had its origins before the end of WWII, even the historic present (+ present perfect) ('We are at the end of WWII. The Cold War has begun.') is stylistically more immediate, less clinical/impersonal.

Comment: "At" seems less good than "by" but if you are emphasising that you're talking about the precise moment, it might feel better to say "at this point in time" rather than "by this time", to better set up your paragraph.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's either your opinion or a matter of historical fact. What the OP's *cited text* says (as *necessary entailment*, not just *possible implication*) is that the Cold War *had already started* by the time WW2 ended. In terms of the use of English, it's not really relevant whether anyone agrees with the "truth value" of that "entailment", but I don't have a problem with it anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's not my opinion. I looked it up, and as Edwin mentioned, 1947 is usually quoted, although its roots may be been earlier.

Comment: But as I said, the "truth value" of the text is irrelevant. We're interested here in what the cited text *means* - whether true ***or*** false.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was used because the author's English wasn't that good. Because normally, you'd write "WWII" and not "the WWII" (see this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=WWII%2C%20the%20WWII&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)), and you could just say "At the end of WWII, the Cold War began".

BUT as others have pointed out, you could justify the past perfect tense with some context.

For example, if the author believed that the Cold War actually began before the end of WWII, they could say: "The day the war ended, I was looking for a way to get from Moscow to Paris but I had no passport and **at the end of WWII, the Cold War had already begun**, so there was no way for me to go."

Then they could separate the long sentence into shorter ones for added drama and there you go, your original sentence is explained and justified :)